# Installed Ubuntu 16.04 on MSI GL62, installing NVidia drivers leads to login loop

Tags: drivers, nvidia, login

I recently got a new laptop running Windows 10.  I wiped it, and am in the process of installing Ubuntu 16.04 in my Ubuntu + Windows 8.1 dual boot.  The laptop has an Nvidia GTX 960m in it as a dedicated graphics card.

I have installed the latest Nvidia proprietary drivers, the package `nvidia-364`, and while it appears as though the screen is at the proper 1920x1080 resolution (as well as in the TTYs reached from pressing ctrl+alt+#), the drivers seem to be having an issue.  The refresh rate on the login screen is very low, for the cursor and menus, but for the password field the refresh rate appears decent.  When actually go to type my password in, the login starts, then the screen goes black (presumably the session manager crashing, or something along those lines), and after a few seconds I'm again presented with a login screen, as if I hadn't tried to log in at all.

I can provide any information that you need.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graphics issues after installing Ubuntu 16.04 with NVIDIA graphics](http://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-installing-ubuntu-16-04-with-nvidia-graphics)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. My solution was:

- REINSTALL SYSTEM
- Do the following:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa`

Check what is the latest nvidia driver for your card and switch the number in `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`.

Now everything works fine.

Comment: After running those commands, the refresh rate issue is basically fixed, however the issue with the display going black and kicking me back to the login screen is still there.  After looking through the X logs it appears as though the X server is actually shutting down.

Comment: Did you reinstall the system?

Comment: Yes, everything exactly as you wrote.